# MKRouteDirections requesting alternate routes

Tags: ios, mapkit

This is a pretty specific question regarding MapKit's MKDirectionsRequest class and maybe only someone with direct knowledge can answer it... I've set the MKDirectionsRequest requestAlternateRoutes property to YES but after running 25-30 tests, I've only been able to get 1 item in the response.routes NSArray from the request. I know the docs say that there's no guarantee of getting more than 1 route response, but, with the number of tests I've run, I would expect at least to see a few requests come back with alternate routes. Would someone know whether its just very rare for MapKit to provide alternate routes, or is there something I might be doing wrong here. Anyone with some MapKit experience in this area who's had this issue before?

Comment: Are you entering start and end addresses which would have *reasonable* alternate routes? Meaning would they have additional routes that are comparable in time or length to the 1st route?

Comment: It seems like they would. I've tried starting and ending addresses within the same city and a bunch of different combinations. I'm also doing it as a walking route (not driving) in case that has something to do with it.